# "commit" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There are many definition of ***commit*** but in this context, I don't sure which definition is.

> Yet in those people who were sleep-deprived, we actually couldn’t find
>   any significant signal whatsoever. So it’s almost as though sleep
>   deprivation had shut down your memory inbox, and any new incoming
>   files — they were just being bounced. You couldn’t effectively
>   ***commit*** new experiences to memory.

Source : https://www.ted.com/talks/matt_walker_sleep_is_your_superpower/transcript#t-44349 (03:13)

Answer (score 1):

**[Commit [something] to memory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit%20%28something%29%20to%20memory)** is a set phrase meaning **memorize**, or learn by heart.

In a similar usage, if you aren't able to commit a piece of information to memory, you could instead commit it to paper (i.e., record it by writing it down).

In this context, the sleep-deprived brain is unable to record memories.

Comment: Notice that it is this meaning of “commit” that is used in this set phrase: *to put (something) in a place or state for keeping:
She decided to commit her ideas to writing.* You will see here (Etymonline) that “commit” has two broad spheres of meaning - 1. to perpetrate/perform and 2. to entrust (as used in your example); https://www.etymonline.com/word/commit#etymonline_v_17233